# How to use ModelBuilder to run tool extract by mask on many rasters in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, iterator, extract-by-mask

I'm trying to extract the same part of multiple rasters (Landsat scenes) using a polygon so I can do a time series.  I've been trying to do it in ArcMap 10.2 ModelBuilder but the following error "ERROR 000581: Invalid parameters. Failed to execute (Extract by Mask)" keeps occuring. I've attached a screen shot of my model.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? [image: model attempt]

Comment: When you double click on `Extract by Mask` are there any red exclamation points by the parameters? For that matter, can you also include a screenshot of the tool opened?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the polygon is actually a polyline. This sounds like a mistake too easy to make; however, it is often overlooked and has happened many a times.

Review the [usage on this page](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/extract-by-mask.htm) to ensure you are doing everything correctly. Specifically:

> The default output format is a geodatabase raster. If an Esri Grid
>   stack is specified as the output format, note that the name cannot
>   start with a number, use spaces, or be more than nine characters in
>   length.

And:

> If the input is a layer created from a multiband raster with more than
>   three bands, the extraction operation will only consider the bands
>   that were loaded (symbolized) by the layer. As a result, the output
>   multiband raster can only have three bands, corresponding to those
>   used in the display of the input layer.

An [explanation of the Iterate Rasters tool](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00400000000z000000.htm) and some [examples of its usage](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#/Examples_of_using_iterators_in_ModelBuilder/00400000001n000000/ESRI_SECTION1_2972801CD03B4BD49859ABB24FE01DB4/) may be helpful for determining any mistakes you may have made.

I would also suggest reviewing the [Geoprocessing Results window](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/executing-tools/using-the-results-window.htm) as this may be able to determine the specific cause of the error.

Lastly, you might even find that the Clip (Data Management) tool will work, [possibly even more efficiently than the Extract By Mask tool.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94469/is-clip-data-management-or-extract-by-mask-spatial-analyst-more-efficient)